# Declaration error in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

```
DELIMITER //

create procedure del()
begin
    declare p_balance decimal(20,4), p_crdr bit, p_debit decimal(20,4), p_credit decimal(20,4);
end //

DELIMITER ;
```

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' p_crdr bit, p_debit decimal(20,4), p_credit decimal(20,4); end' at line 3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't declare multiple variables in one stamement

```
DELIMITER //

create procedure del()
begin
    declare p_balance decimal(20,4);
    declare p_crdr bit;
    declare p_debit decimal(20,4);
    declare p_credit decimal(20,4);
end //

DELIMITER ;
```